# Regular expression and trimming

Tags: r, regex

I have to create a regular expression which, for a given string s, captures the trimmed version of s into group 1. That is, for any string s, calling str_replace(s, re1, "\1") should produce the same output as str_trim(s). This is what I have to pass as the test case. I'm not sure where to begin..

```
for (s in c(
"   this will  be trimmed   ",
"\t\nso will this\n\t  ",
"and this too    "
)) {
stopifnot(identical(
    str_replace(s, re6, "\\1"),
    str_trim(s)))
}
```

My regular expression is re6 = "..."
Thanks!

Comment: Did you meant `identical(str_replace_all(str1, "^\\s+|\\s+$", ""), str_trim(str1))
[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `trimws`

```
trimws(str1)
```

---

If we are using `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
identical(str_replace_all(str1, "^\\s+|\\s+$", ""), str_trim(str1))
#[1] TRUE
```

Here the pattern used is one or more spaces (`\\s+`) either from the start (`^`) or (`|`) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blanks (`""`)

It is also possible to capture as a group and then replace it with the backreference (tried in the OP's post)

```
re6 <- "^\\s*(.*\\S)\\s+$"
identical(str_trim(str1), str_replace(str1, re6, "\\1"))
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c(
 "   this will  be trimmed   ",
 "\t\nso will this\n\t  ",
 "and this too    "
 )
```

Comment: 1 sec apart. You win;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Use a regular expression with `gsub`:

```
gsub("(^\\s+|\\s+$)", "", ss)
#[1] "this will  be trimmed" "so will this"          "and this too"
```

Explanation: `\\s+` matches `>0` whitespace characters, at the beginning (`^`) or at the end (`$`) of the string.

---

### Method 2

Use `trimws`:

```
trimws(ss);
[1] "this will  be trimmed" "so will this"          "and this too"
```

---

### Sample data

```
ss <- c(
"   this will  be trimmed   ",
"\t\nso will this\n\t  ",
"and this too    "
)
```

Comment: @steviekay I just updated my solution. Have a look at method 1.